# Anti Slashes added to Python Pandas JSON dump

Tags: json, python-2.7, pandas

When using dumping to JSON a pandas dataframe :

```
vv={}
vv['table1']= df_perdate.to_json(orient='records')
vv2= json.dumps(vv)
```

I have double anti-slash added to vv2 :

```
{[{\\"dateday\\":20170326,\\"nb_user_unique\\":277,
\\"nb_hannou\\":1366,\\"nb_log\\":1366,
\\"nb_dau\\":0,\\"application_id\\":68,
\\"group_id\\":10}]"}'
```

How can I remove the double anti-slash ?
When I try to replace by replace(), because of special character \ ,
cannot remove it.

Comment: This is not double backslash. Note the `\ ` is also escaping in python, so in string representation, `\\ ` is in fact `\ `. You can check this is so by running `print(vv2)`. The reason there is a backslash there in first place is because `vv['table']` is a `str` and not a `dict`, so there is need to escape all the `"` that appear in the string.

Comment: This JSON will be read by javascript.... How to remove this before to http

Comment: Can you add and example of how you want `vv2` to look like? (If you remove the backslash in your current code, the json will be invalid)